# Set default state by routing with ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have some controller

```
NewController.extend({
    ors: [],
    ands: [],
    .......
```

in my controller ors, ands and another variable change.

How do when does it change routing variables set default state?

Is there such hook, so set default state ?

In angular2 i cann't know when variables i must setting by default. In angular2 is zonejs and does it without me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are singleton that means it will not be instantiated again. there are some hook in Route you can reset the controller. but by default there is hook is provided in controller.

1. [`resetController`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/methods/resetController?anchor=resetController) A hook you can use to reset controller values either when the model changes or the route is exiting.

```
import Ember from 'ember';    
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  resetController(controller, isExiting, transition) {
    //isExiting is true on leaving the route.
    if (isExiting) { 
      controller.set('page', 1);
    }
  }
});
```

2. [`deactivate()`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/methods/resetController?anchor=deactivate) where you can use `this.controller` and set all the properties to initial value.

Comment: thankyou for the answer. Am i right understood i must set variable "by hand" in hook, It doesn't make ember. Ember provide only hook?

Comment: Yes. we need to manually reset controller properties in the hook

Comment: Ok. Thankyou from help